# ruby on rails on CentOS?

Tags: centos, ruby, redmine

I'm trying to install RedMine (www.redmine.org) which is an awesome project management tool. I have access to a CentOS machine which is supposed to host it. I found some guide specifying how to install an old version of ruby and I tried to install it and then update to no avail. The latest version of rails requires a newer version of ruby than what I've got installed.

Could someone point me in the direction of how I can upgrade that ruby version? Yum hasn't registered it so I'm kind of stuck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good starting point may be the slicehost [articles](http://articles.slicehost.com/centos) on ruby on centos, but if your looking for the latest and greatest in terms of the newest version you will havre to compile from source or find a repo which you trust etc. just from a quick google something along the lines of [this](http://www.how-to-linux.com/2008/12/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-centos-52/) will work but like i said you need to a:) trust the repository and b:)be aware that you are deviating from the stable branch of the OS etc.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it after a lot of fighting and a little learning. Your proposed links would have helped me and any other peer stumbling upon the same problem so I marked as answer.

Comment: Phil your welcome, ruby's not really my think it was more of a nudge in the right direction kind of thing.............